# How to submit form in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-submit

I have code on views bellow:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("DeleteItem", "Test", new { id = 3 }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form" }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <a class="submit-process" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</a>
}
```

Script code:

```
$('.submit-process').click(function () {
    if (confirm('You want delete?')) {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    }
    else return false;
});
```

And Action in Controlller Test bellow:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteItem(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

When I click submit, It not found action DeleteItem, and message error:

> The view 'DeleteItem' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Comment: Is this method `DeleteItem` in Test controller?

Comment: @SmitPatel : DeleteItem is Action in TestController

Comment: `return View();` means you return the view named `DeleteItem.cshtml` in the `TestController`. If you want to return a different view, then you need to specify its name - `return View("MyOtherView");`

Comment: The real question is why would you want to return the view after deleting the item (that makes no sense since the item no longer exists. You should be using `return RedirectToAction(....)` to redirect to another view.

Comment: Also specify your `Viewname` in the `return view("ViewName")` if you want to redirect to the view which name is different from your `ActionName`, See more in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Muecke. I not define action return view from action DeleteItem.

Comment: Thanks @Smit Patel!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This thing is occurred because you have not specified your `viewName` in

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteItem(int id)
{
    return view('YOUR VIEW NAME');
}
```

And your example this type of error may occurred.

```
The view 'DeleteItem' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Test/DeleteItem.aspx
~/Views/Test/DeleteItem.ascx
~/Views/Shared/DeleteItem.aspx
~/Views/Shared/DeleteItem.ascx
~/Views/Test/DeleteItem.cshtml
~/Views/Test/DeleteItem.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/DeleteItem.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/DeleteItem.vbhtml
```

When you don't set a `viewname` in return view(), It's **automatically takes the Method name** as a `viewname` and try to find it in above locations.

Look more [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/db2972/return-view-with-viewname-in-controller-sample-in-mvc-day/)

Learn more about [Controllers and Action Methods in ASP.NET MVC Applications.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd410269(v=vs.100).aspx)